# How to Install both java7 and java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, java-7

How to install both java7 and java8 in windows7 machine.

If Yes then what is the order and any switch options from java7 to java8 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can install any number of `JDK` instances on your computer (and use them in projects or tools), but only one can be used as the main with `JAVA_HOME` env variable and its `bin` dir should be added to the `PATH` value like `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`.

`JAVA_HOME` location is used by most software to detect default `JDK` location and binaries dir in `PATH` allows you to use `JDK` apps like `javac` in the terminal or by direct calls from anywhere

If everything is correct then you should see desired java version in terminal just typing:

```
C:\Users\Admin>%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java -version
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)
```

Linux, Mac OS X or Win installations slightly differ from each other, but you can find all the necessary instructions at the [Oracle site](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/install_overview.html).

Answer (score 0):

As Cootri has stated - you can install any number of Java versions on windows machines.
JAVA_HOME and PATH will be needed.
Here is a screen print showing two different java versions by invoking frm each version's bin directory
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can install various JDK's and according to your project need you can specify the JAVA_HOME variable.
if you wish to use JDK 7 for some project set your JAVA_HOME path with JDK 7 or vice-versa.
say, you are using linux OS you can set it like..

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/<the one which you wish to use>
```