# Can I have instances of both java 7 & 8 running together

Tags: java, ireport

I am working on a project which runs on java 8, but I frequently use jasper reports which runs on java 7 for generating PDF reports. Problem is that I have to switch between the 7 & 8 versions for this. Is there any way I can let the system know which version of Java to use for which applications. My tomcat server is wrapped within a [Hybris](https://help.hybris.com/6.0.0/hcd/8c39af1286691014b2daed4f092998ca.html) server instance which is run externally, so changing compliance level in Eclipse is of no help.

Comment: but you need set the Environmental variables properly also need to select the default java version for every Java Applications you are working

Comment: I am doing the same and wondering if there is any way or hack so that I can work on both simultaneously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe my question was misunderstood, but I found a way to acheive what I intended to do.
Set your JAVA_HOME to 1.7 version and open iReports application(it did not open if version is set to 1.8). Then reset JAVA_HOME back to 1.8 and run your application normally. Once iReports has started, there is no further issue while developing your reports.
It is more of a hack than a proper solution, but works well enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

As per described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36174699/how-to-install-both-java7-and-java-8) you can install any number of JDKs. The system default will be the one you added to the PATH variable under environment variables. When you create a new project in NetBeans select the desired JDK location. (Java 7 or Java8). You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128256/change-jre-in-netbeans-project).

Comment: Please refer the extra info added to the question as I think my question is being misunderstood.